# What is the fastest way to check the sign of an int256 in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, integers

Given an int256 number n, I want to get the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) of n:

- If n is positive, get 1
- If n is negative, get -1
- If n is 0, get 0

I know that I can do:

```
function foo(int256 x) external {
    if (x > 0) {
        // ...
    } else if (x < 0) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this introduces three logical branches in my code, which means gas.

Is there a faster approach? Maybe via some sort of bit manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing the code, the idea is to use the [Ternary operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/c-ternary-operator/).

`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Be careful, since in Solidity `0.8` version overflows/underflows cause a revert, so if you are using `^0.8.x` you will need to use an `unchecked {...}` block.

Code before Solidity `0.8.0` release:

```
function sign(int256 x) external pure returns (int8) {
    return int8(((0 < x) ? 1 : 0) - ((x < 0) ? 1 : 0 ));
}
```

Code after Solidity `0.8.0` release:

```
function sign(int256 x) external pure returns (int8) {
    unchecked {
        return int8(((0 < x) ? 1 : 0) - ((x < 0) ? 1 : 0 ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't work out a single-liner that involved shifting everything right to check the sign bit. It'd be relatively straightforward if `bool` -> `int` type conversions were allowed, similar to other languages. In which case you could do something like:

```
int result = (x != 0) | (x >> 255);
```

But you can't. (Someone else may know otherwise!)

So something a bit dumber might have to do:

```
  function foo(int256 x) external pure returns (int) {
    int a =  x > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    int b = x < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    return a - b;
  }
```

Again, the ternaries are because we can't implicitly convert `bool` -> `int`. (And ternary operators are effectively introducing branching... so is this any better than the original question?)

You may find the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) page useful for similar types of stuff :-)

Comment: Perhaps one could speed up your function by wrapping the code in an "unchecked" block. `a-b` can never {over,under}flow.

Comment: Yep, agreed - alberto had a very good point.